# When $A^TA = I$, what matrix is orthogonal to what?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, self-learning

When $A^TA = I$, I am told it is orthogonal. What does that mean?

$A = \begin{bmatrix}cos\theta & & -sin\theta \\ \\ sin\theta & & cos\theta\end{bmatrix}, A^T = \begin{bmatrix}cos\theta & & sin\theta \\ \\ -sin\theta & & cos\theta\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: A is an orthogonal matrix on it's own

Comment: You could start by asking yourself what $A$ is.

Comment: It is a rotation matrix.

Comment: That is *the definition* of an orthogonal matrix. It means that a matrix (with real entries) is called orthogonal if and only if its inverse is equal to its transpose.

Comment: @user122358: Nope. The diagonal 2x2 matrix with entries -1 and +1 is orthogonal, but I wouldn't call it a rotation matrix.

Comment: See also [Why is an orthogonal matrix called orthogonal?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/650379)

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen You raise a good point. Your example has determinant $-1$ and is sometimes called an improper orthogonal matrix instead of a special orthogonal Martz (which has determinant $1$). The latter is a rotation matrix and the former combines a rotation (in this case the identity!) with a reflection.

Answer (score 2):

It means that the row vectors (and also the column vectors) form an orthogonal basis, that means if $A$ has dimension $n\times n$, $A$ consists of $n$ linear independent and pairwise orthogonal vectors spanning $\mathbb R_n$

Comment: Even more, the vectors form am orthonormal-system, the additional property is that the vectors have length $1$

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the term is *suggestive* of matrix $\mathbf{A}$ being orthogonal to another matrix $\mathbf{B}$ in some sense like $$\mathbf{A}.\mathbf{B}=0$$ as it would be if $A$ and $B$ were orthogonal vectors. However this is *not* what it means when considering matrices.

For matrices ìt refers to the set of columns being orthogonal (actually orthonormal) in the usual sense for vectors

$$\mathbf{c_i}.\mathbf{c_j}=\delta_{ij}$$ The same is true for the set of rows.

Because the columns are orthogonal (and rows)  the matrix itself is *called* orthogonal. These matrices have the property you stated.

(Try it with the columns or rows of your 2x2 matrix.)