# The terminology of orthogonal matrix vs. orthonormal matrix

Tags: orthogonal-matrices

I know the definition of an orthogonal matrix. Also there are orthonormal basis. And if two vectors are orthogonal, their scalar product is zero etc. It seems the name "orthonormal matrix" more relevant to other definitions. My question is **why it is called orthogonal matrix** instead of orthonormal matrix or by another name? Is there any deep reason behind that?
Thanks

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/650379/why-is-an-orthogonal-matrix-called-orthogonal

Comment: Thanks. It seems it is called orthogonal matrix mainly due to historical reason